# how can I use separate database for every application in django

Tags: python, database, django

I have app1 and app2, I wanna app1 use db1 and app2 use db2

the approach I found is to using database router, a little bit complicated

I wanna know is there any simple way?

Can I just config it in settings.py

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams one would want this because, you have cases when you have a separate app for hash keys which you want in a separate db to keep them private

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The correct way is to use routers.  It is very simple.  See `MyAppRouter` in django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example:

```
class MyAppRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the myapp application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in myapp is involved"
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the myapp app only appears on the 'other' db"
        if db == 'other':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return False
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks,I will go for routers :D

Answer (score 3):

I think the right answer is here: http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings. If you have many applications and want a separate database for each, you put

```
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'app1':'db1', 'app2':'db2', 'app3':'db3', 'app4':'db4'}
DATABASE_ROUTERS += ['DatabaseAppsRouter']
```

into settings.py.